# Java Math.pow issue

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I am working on a program which needs to cube a number.  Long story short, I need to compare the number to a string, so I need to get rid of the decimal place a double gives when I convert to string.  To do this, I used `Math.round` and saved it as a `long`.  This works fine for relatively normal numbers, but the numbers can go up to 999,999.

I used 275393 (a given test number, so I'm assuming it must be correct for the problem I'm working on) and neither a calculator nor the computer seemed to get the correct answer.  The correct answer is supposed to contain 123457 somewhere in the results, but the calculator has 12346 (which I think is just rounding, as it stops listing numbers after this) and the computer has 123456 (the computer stops listing numbers after this point).  Is rounding it giving it the problem (it shouldn't because I'm pretty sure it only rounds to the tenths place, but who knows)?  Or is it something else?

Comment: Try using [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of a double.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Math.pow()` takes two `double`s and returns a `double`. There is not enough precision in a `double` to represent 275393<sup>3</sup> = 20886164356123457 (exact).

The solution is to use [`BigInteger.pow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Answer (score 3):

A `double` has limited precision. Instead, use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to compare the number to a string, so I need to get rid of the decimal place a double gives when I convert to string.

Do it the other way around.  Convert the `String` to a number, then compare it to the `double` (with a small tolerance to account for inaccurate binary representations of float point numbers).